# TotalCount возвращает undefined

Tags: extjs

В *Extjs* делаю интерфейс и там мне от *store* надо взять *totalCount* но когда я его через *console.log* вывожу он undefined у меня.

```
Ext.define('Catalog.store.MVD.TrgTransportStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Catalog.model.MVD.TrgTransportModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'services/MTrgTransport',
        headers:{
            Accept:'application/json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'list',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

это мой *store*. `console.log(1, this.store2);` делаю консол лог приходит это

```
data: constructor
events: Object
eventsSuspended: 0
filters: constructor
groupers: constructor
groups: constructor
hasListeners: HasListeners
lastOptions: Object
loading: false
model: constructor()
modelDefaults: null
pageSize: 25
proxy: constructor
removed: Array[0]
sorters: constructor
totalCount: 6079093
__proto__: Object
```

но когда делаю `console.log(3, this.store2.totalCount)` выдает *undefined*